# Designing an authentication system in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Ok, so I am building a login page and register page for my website. I got two options either to use built-in ASP.NET Login controls or my own custom. I have read somewhere on stackoverflow not to built your own custom login controls as you will never get it right. I don't know why? So what are the design considerations and pitfalls in building a login/register/password reset page, system? If I should not use my own custom and rather use built-in, then why?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the existing membership functionality?

Comment: There are so many questions about this around SO, you've even highlighted yourself that you've read it on SO before. A simple search brings up a vast amount of answers relating to your question.

Comment: They all told not to, but didn't give the reason....

Comment: @Oded I find building my own more easy, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: "I have read somewhere". Where? Links please.

Comment: **not to built your own custom login controls as you will never get it right** :O ...where did you find that ???

Comment: Easier? Possibly. Faster? No. More directly suited to your own needs? Definitely. Chances that you are overlooking something? Very high.

Comment: Is your question about using your own MembershipProvider or build your own login page instead of using login controls in the toolbox?

Comment: I mean using my own login page.

Comment: Its up to you to use your own login controls to build login page. There is nothing wrong in using the built-in controls as well if you dont want to reinvent the wheel. The problem lies is how you authenticate the users.

Comment: Can you be more elaborate? Actually I also wanted to know what are the design considerations and pitfalls in building a login/register/password reset page, system? I hope I am not shooting arrows in the dark.

Comment: @LetaDuetse replied in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have fun building your own login page. I suspect that the articles you read related to writing your own authentication / authorisation framework - which can be tricky. Unless you have a good reason to move off the built in asp.net membership system (like not liking GUIDs for IDs) I would stick with that as it is a tried and tested solution.

In terms of building your own login / pwd reset page - go for it - its just a form post: just remember to make the login page SSL or your users will be sending their password unencrypted from client to server.

Comment: Yeah, that's it("Have fun building your own login page", Was that sarcasm?). I have build my own login page before and using SSL is obvious. But since I have done it once so I may go wrong this time, maybe I will miss something crucial. And I have got no experience working with asp.net membership system. Anyways I will try it out.

Comment: Not sarcasm - encouragement! Using the built in stuff is a bit boring and generic I think. I've made some awesome login pages!

Comment: Plus, by building your own login / pwd reset you get more of an idea of how the membership provider works as you have to do some of the plumbing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is widely considered wise to never implement security-related frameworks by hand if you have the choice.  It is very difficult to get these right, and getting them wrong makes your application vulnerable to hacking.

If it's just a question of the login UI (rather than the underlying authentication mechanism), this is not as big of a concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered your question for whether to use built-in login controls that comes with Visual Studio in the comments.

For design and considerations check here for [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh.aspx) and [WindowsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/907hb5w9.aspx) . If your authentication is straight forward stick to builtin Membership Provider another eg [here](http://odetocode.com/articles/427.aspx)